# HTTP requests between apps on different PCF domains

Tags: http, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I currently have a node server deployed in PCF that periodically makes GET requests to other applications in PCF.

Some of the applications are in the same domain, and those GET requests are working; however, when I make requests to apps in a different domain, they timeout.

To summarize:

```
MyApplication   = NodeJS server running at MyApp.apps.dev.company.int
DevApplication  = Application running at DevApp.apps.dev.company.int
ProdApplication = Application running at ProdApp.apps.prod.company.int

GET Requests from MyApplication to DevApplication work, 
but GET requests from MyApplication to ProdApplication do not.

GET requests from localhost work for both DevApplication and ProdApplication.
```

What is causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Inside the platform, it's possible that there are application security groups blocking access. That is the only thing within the platform that can block outgoing traffic. That said like any network traffic, you be able to resolve the DNS entries, you must be able to route traffic between the two networks (client & server), and there must not be any firewalls blocking access. These are all questions for your platform operator, so it is best that you contact your platform operator & inquire about egress traffic access & what might be blocking your traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Are these apps deployed on same space or different? You might be missing the ASG (Application security group) if they are on different space... ASG manages the egress traffic from your app and works at space level..

If prod and dev are completely different foundations then possibly it might be blocked and allowed to access the app via some other domain and possibly fronted by F5